# Why is this NSOutlineView ignoring layout constraints?

Tags: cocoa, layout, autolayout

At first the UI looks like this. There is an `NSWindow`, its content view, and an `NSOutlineView`.  The `NSOutlineView` has a blue background. High priority constraints set the space between the `NOutlineView` and it's superview to 0.

```
@"|[_outlineView]|"
@"V:|[_outlineView]|"
```

[image]

Now I open or close the "FirstProject" item in the outline. The outline view shrinks into the corner of it's superview.

[image]

If I click on those blue constraints, the console shows that the constraint "wants" a distance of 0, but ends up with 191.

```
2013-06-24 22:27:18.354 Test[25202:403] Clicked on visualized constraint: (
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x10015e470 H:[outlineView]-(0)-|   
(Names: outlineView:0x100155430, '|':NSView:0x10061aa80 )> 
(Actual Distance - pixels):191")
```

So, it's breaking the constraint. Why? I have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and the only constraints I see are the 4 around the NSOutlineView, asking for 0 space.
The `intrinsicContentSize` of the outline view is (-1,-1) (ie, `NSViewNoInstrinsicMetric`)